# reliable method to find keycodes

Tags: bash, keyboard, bind, inputrc

I'm trying to setup some key binds in bash and it seems to me that the recommended methods (>read, sed -n l, ctrl+V) of getting the strings that correlate to keypresses aren't giving me correct results that I can use with the bind command.

For example `esc` comes out as ^[ but the correct string for bind is \e.
`alt`+`c` comes out as ^[c but the string that worked is \ec.

Reading man bash also didn't help, as my first attempt for `alt`+`c` was \M-c due to reading man but that also didn't work.

How can I do it correctly?

my setup is windows-terminal/WSL/ubuntu/bash

Comment: You may find the `INITIALIZATION FILE` section of `man readline` helpful

Comment: I see \M- for "meta" character which I assume means alt because I don't see anything in particular for alt.

Comment: To explain further my confusion:
the man says M-x means Meta-x and metafying x can happen in the way of alt+x or esc->x. 
later on the man says:
 \M-   meta prefix
 \e     an escape character
but then why is \M- not the same as \e?
and I can say from experience that using "\ep" for a keybind works the same when I press alt+p or esc->p. so \ep means "metafied p". So what does \M-p mean?